# Printing from mobile device

Tags: cordova, printing, extjs

We are developing a Sencha Touch app that needs to have option to print on both android as well as iOS.

We are open to use phonegap to achieve this.Is there any phonegap plugin that can help us connect to wifi printers and send job to it.Please let me know if  there are any other ways through which we can achieve this task.

Comment: Have you looked at this (iOS only) : https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/PrintPlugin

Comment: Have you tried RhoMobile? http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhoelements/apd-overview